# node.js - console.log does not work in public/javascript/ file

Tags: node.js, console.log

console.log does not work for me when I place it in a function in public/javascripts folder.

My current node.js folder structure is:

- views
- routes
- public

  - javascripts > utils.js

In utils.js, i have this function

```
function goToGoogle () {
  alert ('Hello World');
  console.log('Hello World');
}
```

The alert() command works fine, but not the console.log

I've tried the console.log in other js files in the routes/ directory and it outputs to the terminal just fine.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the code is in `public` then I assume it runs in the browser. That means messages will come up in the browser's console, not Node's console. In Chrome for instance you go to `Tools -> Javascript Console` in the menu.

The reason it works in other files is because the JS for routes runs in Node and thus uses Node's console.

Comment: yes, i just Chrome View->Developer->Javascript Console and it works great! Thanks!!!

Comment: Why `console.log` is only coming in Node's console? I am using Shell Client(SSH) as Node's console. It doesn't outputs `console.info`, `console.warn` etc. Why this happens? I think, `alert` will not support in Shell client.

Comment: @JustinJohn I'm sorry I don't understand what you are asking. The source of the issue here is that the browser and Node are two separate JavaScript execution environments. If the code runs in the browser via a `<script>` tag it will print in the browser's console, and since the browser supports `alert`, you can use alert. In the case of Node, your code is running inside the Node application, meaning it will output to Node's terminal.

Comment: What I asked is whether Node's terminal support all `console` statements in it? From my experience, I get is `console.log` is supported, but rest `console.warn`, `console.info` etc are not supported in node's terminal.

Comment: @JustinJohn They working for me on 0.10.0, do you have an old version of Node? If you can, please make a new question since this isn't related to my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a solution for users of nodejs in ssh-environment.
Because there is no included browser, you can use firebase (https://firebase.google.com) for realtime-console.log() in your browser.

[Output to Chrome console from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704292/output-to-chrome-console-from-node-js/37956154#37956154)