# Get console.log results from node to execute in web console

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I've built a node application that outputs the result in the terminal and works fine. But, I want to output the result to the web console so I can query it from the browser - how do I do this?

A second alternative can be that the result is being processed as a file in a json format so I can query it through jquery and get.JSON.

Thanks!

Comment: while running node use `node [file].js > result.log` result.log is the file where you will get all logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output to Chrome console from Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704292/output-to-chrome-console-from-node-js)

Comment: What browser is the question about? Firefox, if I recall correctly, implements a protocol for remote debugging. Chrome probably does as well.

Comment: I'm using Chromes' console. The problem is that there's no logs in the browser at all and I think this is because I don't log it that way.

Comment: @Chilibiff Of course, `console.log()` calls show up in the console where you are running JavaScript, I thought that part was clear. You need some specific debugging library.

Comment: I solved a bit manually but the solution provided works. I know get a json file by using this command in the command line: 

`node app.js > result.json`

Comment: @Chilibiff glad my answer helped you out ;) cheers buddy!

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` in node.js logs the data to the console.  If you want it to log the data to the browser, you'll need to do an ajax get or any `get` function to get the data from the node server.

You do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/get(your node url)",
    type: "GET"
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

that's how you log a Json to the console in the browser, but there's no direct log to the browser from node, because it's server sided and not client sided.

---

Eventually this answer helped out and then he just had to do `node app.js > result.json` in the console to run it. Hope this answer helps out anyone in the future.

Comment: Thanks, should I do the ajax call in my index.html file or in the node app? I've created a result.json file which I want to query via jQuery.

Comment: You could also make a new js file and link that script to your html document, then use that ajax fucntion on click or whatever you want it to activate on. Writing js / jquery / ajax inside a html document is unclear, but of course, it's possible.