# HTTP Server and Console.log at Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node js and trying to learn with a few examples, so my requirement is I should get output in browser console mode, I want to check it via HTTP server as well as in console, but data is printed only on browser page but didn't get any console output.

Code:

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Data render at browser page');
    console.log('print in browser console ');   
}).listen(4000);
```

Comment: `console.log('print in browser console ')` <- that code is running on the _server_, not in the browser.

Comment: You cannot show logs you are printing in the server in the browser, it is just impossible because code is executing in different machines.

Comment: @A.Llorente  I didn't get it, can't we run in browser, however we r running at  4000 port

Comment: Yes, but you run the server on port 4000 and you are showing the console (that's one machine) and then you access it through your browser (other machine). The fact that your server is running on the same hardware as your client doesn't make them the same "machine", or better called "execution environments"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send a HTML response and add a script tag:

```
/********** Node.js start ********/
/* This code is run in Node.js */
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('' +
`<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Data render at browser page
    <script>
      /********** Browser start ********/
      /* This code is run in the browser */
      console.log('print in browser console ');
      /********** Browser end ********/
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`);
    console.log('print in Node.js engine');   
}).listen(4000);
/********** Node.js end ********/
```

Answer (score 1):

Node Js do not run in the browser so, you can't see any `console.log()` output to the browser console instead it will show in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing if you are using node.js for the first time because it runs on the server instead of the client browser.

Having said that, is actually now possible to pipe your node console output to the browser console. Please check out this github repo [connect-browser-logger on github](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/browser-logger)

You can also use `NodeMonkey` as mentioned here - [Output to Chrome console from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704292/output-to-chrome-console-from-node-js)